# In Azure AD what is the minimum privilege necessary to give a Guest Inviter the ability to add the invitees to groups?

Tags: azure-active-directory

As a **Global administrator** role, when I add a **Guest User** to the tenant, the UI allows me to add the invitee to groups.

[image]

However, as a **Guest Inviter** role, it does **not** allow me to do this.
[image]

So, what is the minimum privileged configuration that I need to give my "project manager people" the ability to add guest users and associate them with **specific** groups?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still trying to determine how they can get that specific groups box in the invite window to appear for normal users, not sure that possible. 
However, to answer your question. As long as those PM people are "owners" of those groups in question, they will have the ability to add the guests to those groups. 
although its 1-2 extra steps. they would have to go to Groups instead of Users, click on the group they want and click add member. that's basically the only way to limit them to be able to add members to certain groups. 
To make it easier to manage, I would create something like a PM Owner Group manage the membership of that group, then add that group to all the other groups you want those set of users to be able to add guests/members to.

But if you absolutely need the little group section as part of the invite window, my fear is it may need more permissions than you should ever give to a PM. However I will update if I find the exact permission.

Comment: Good idea on the PM Owner Group, however it looks like you cannot add a group as an owner of another group.  You can only add users as owners.  Am I missing something?  Also, I noticed that you can't assign the Guest Inviter AAD role to a group either. So, I don't know what that group buys me at this point.

Comment: Hmm, I could have sworn I was able to add groups as owners for other groups last week .. if that's the case, then you would have to essentially add those PMs owners individually then. not really ideal.

Comment: Well, let me know if you are able to, because I was not able to add an AAD security group as an owner of other AAD security groups I created.  That said, I have already run into other issues that were specific to me, but that was with regards to Azure DevOps and AAD integration.